# Does TensorFlow and PyTorch have any specialized matrix multiplication operation for Symmetric or Triangular matrices?

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow2.0, linear-algebra, blas, intel-mkl

Does TensorFlow and PyTorch have any specialized functions for multipling matrices with special properties?

For example, consider the matrix multiplication:

```
C := AB  where A and B are n x n
```

The cost of a regular **matmul** is approximately 2n^3 floating point operations (FLOPs). However, if A is triangular, I can perform the same multiplication for half the number of FLOPs in C using an MKL kernel for triangular matrix multiplication - TRMM. Is it possible to do something like this in TensorFlow and PyTorch?